# binding scope property with a dash in html template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For some reason, I have to use dash in property like `test-name` and cannot use `testName` or `testname`:

```
angular.module('testApp')
.controller('TestController',function($scope){
  //neither 'testname' nor 'testName', only 'test-name'
  $scope['test-name'] = 'Test name...';
});
```

And now I want to bind it in the html template:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
  This is {{test-name}}
</div>
```

I've also tried `{{testname}}` and `{{testName}}` but doesn't work. <sup>keeping `$scope['test-name']`</sup>

Is there any way to it?

---

Currently this produce the result like this:

```
This is 0
```

But the expected result is like this:

```
This is Test name...
```

Comment: cant you assign it to an array or variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it should work:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
  This is {{this['test-name']}}
</div>
```

Comment: I had tested previously {{['test-name']}} was not working but binding `this` worked. great.

Answer (score 0):

That is because when `{{test-name}}` is parsed by `$parseProvider` and `Lexer` in angular, the `-` is recoginzed as an minus operator.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/parse.js#L1005

`{{this['test-name']}}` should work